# For what values is the expression $\sqrt[6-x^2]{x}$ well defined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

I have the following expression:

## $$\sqrt[6-x^2]{x}$$

How can I find the values for which this expression if well defined?

I have the following options:

**A.** $5$ elements

**B.** $7$ elements

**C.** an interval

**D.** $4$ elements

**E.** no elements

The correct answer is **B.** $7$ elements, but I don't know how can I arrive at this result.

Comment: Without the context the problem is remedial and the answers are bogus.  It is well defined for all complex numbers or if the problem is considering only real numbers, it is well defined for all nonnegative numbers.  Are the answers for the number of rational  numbers or the number of integers for which the expression is well defined?

Answer (score 2):

I shall assume you want the expression to represent only real values here. Then it is equal to $$x^{\frac{1}{6-x^2}}.$$

First, this makes sense only if $x^2\ne 6.$ Secondly, we must have $x>0$ if this is to have a definite real value. Thus, I would say that there is an interval of possible values of $x.$

Perhaps there is a tacit agreement between you and your tester that you only want integer or rational values? That's the only time when a finite number of arguments may be justifiable.

Comment: The exact statement is *The set of values of x for which $\sqrt[6-x^2]{x}$ is defined is:* and then the choices are listed. I agree that it seems ambigous, but the answers given are usually correct so I still think the actual answer is **B.** $7$ elements. Would we get $7$ if we'd be solving in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Could you please show me how would you solve this if $x$ is indeed integral?

Comment: @user1502 I don't know if we'd get exactly seven possible values of $x$ satisfying the given conditions; my point is that to have only *finitely* many values of your expression (and thus finitely many arguments) then it is obviously *necessary* that it be integral.

Comment: Isn't it necessary for the root to be integral by default? What I mean is this: isn't it a condition that $6 - x^2$ be integral in $\sqrt[6 - x^2]{x}$? Or is it possible for that number to be something other that a number from $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @user1502 That's why we say the question is ambiguous. A root need not be integral, or even rational.